# Bare metal backup

Tags: server, backup, maas, rsync

I'm renting out some bare metal machines and am finally starting to automate the process of provisioning.
The idea is to setup a few bare metal machines and manage them via MAAS. I would like to automatically take backups of the machines if the user desires so.

I'd use the backups either for restoring data in case of trouble, or to be able to save a machine before launching another OS & redeploying the previous machine later.

How would I best go about this? I was thinking to create an admin SSH user and use rsync to a storage machine in the local network but I'm doubting if this is the best practice.

Edit: The machines run Ubuntu 18.04, 20.04 or Centos 7 and only have a single hard drive.
The machine running MAAS (rack & region controller) is on Ubuntu 18.04.

Comment: To start with, which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]